# html5 hide all div and show one on button click

Tags: javascript, css, html

I got a few buttons setup and I can have them show and hide divs on click that part works fine. But I would like to know if it would be possible to have them hide all the other divs when one is showing as well to have divone show up on load.

Buttons:

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#divone">One</button>
        <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#divetwo">two</button>
        <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#divthree">Threee</button>
```

Divs:

```
<div id="divone" class="collapse">div one here</div> <div id="divetwo" class="collapse">div twohere</div> <div id="divthree" class="collapse">div three here</div>
```

Comment: Share us your JS please.

Comment: @Breau Have you got any css or javascript to accompany this HTML? Please post any relevant code

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple one. Keeping your classes and HTML markup, I would add this css style to force the element to be displayed..and use jQuery to add/remove that class as needed.

```
.unhide{
        display: block !important;
    }
```

Next, after importing jQuery, use this short script to handle the click logic:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".btn").click(function(){
        $('.collapse').removeClass('unhide');
        $($(this).data("target")).addClass('unhide');
    })
</script>
```

To explain the logic here, when any button is clicked, we first remove the "force to display" class that we just created. Then we get the data-target of that specific button, and insert that value as the ID and we use it in the second step to add the "force to display" class. (the double money signs)

You could always get more creative with the class names if you'd like!

Comment: why are you creating a new class instead of updating a current class? and why the need for block? [There is no necessity to add jquery when using javascript  btw]

Comment: OP doesn't show enough ... no JS or CSS ... but I would probably just toggle the "collapse" class — not, as Rachel points out, add another class to it.